# ipad/iphone functionality issue

Tags: html, mobile-safari, anchor

I have the following html mark up that works in all browsers but when viewed in iPhone / ipad, the drop down list will not open.

The reason for using an empty anchor tag was to keep styling the parent link the same way as the rest of my menu links due to my current css rules; but at the same time prevent the parent link to redirect the page.

Is this a very wrong approach and the cause to the issue I am experiencing?

```
<ul class="primary-nav">
   <li><a>Group links</a>
    <ul id="sub_nav" class="sub">  
    <li><a href="/">Link</a></li>  
    <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>  
    <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>  
    <li><a href="/">Link 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

I can see there is the following javascript in place for the menu

```
    // Test is browser is IE
    var browserIsIE = null;
    if (jQuery.browser.msie == true) {
        browserIsIE = true;
    } else {
        browserIsIE = false;
    };
 // primary and secondary nav hover for IE < 9
    if (browserIsIE == true) {
        $(".primary-nav li, .secondary-nav li").hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    };
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean in safari its not working?

Comment: I assume there is some JavaScript that you are not showing us?

Comment: Sorry JavaScript code referenced in my initial code now. Safari works on desktop. The problem is only experienced on iphone / ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is when `browserIsIE` evaluates to `false`, nothing will happen. The if statement requires it to be `true` before it attaches a `hover` event handler to your drop down menu.

Once you fix that, you will quickly realise that you can't `hover` on touch devices. This post https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/re-thinking-hover-functionality-with-touchscreens-in-mind covers some nice ideas you could implement.

Comment: I am not very experienced with JavaScript or even jQuery. I thank you for your comment. It does make sense to me now why it's not working. Is it possible in my case  to use jQuery code replacing hover with on-tap menus and what that will be?

Comment: If the primary nav links don't go anywhere then you could bind click events to them to show the `sub_nav`. Those click events can be bound inside `if ('ontouchstart' in window) { // your click event handling code here }`. If the primary nav links do go somewhere then you may need additional links to show the `sub_nav`, maybe small down arrows?

Comment: Within my navigation, I have  5 top links. All of them have links and href="" attached to them. 2 of those links have sub menus. Only those 2 top parent links do not go anywhere.

Comment: In that case, I suggest rethinking your drop down menus a bit and including some sort of additional element to trigger the drop down on touch devices. That is a whole different question all together though :)

Comment: Not sure if this is stable enough as I thought I had it originally before I reported the issue. I have added the empty href="#" back on my links now and it seems to work on mobile safari as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are watching for the hover event. There isn't a hover event on mobile devices. There's no cursor and, as such, no way to hover.

The browser will attempt to handle it, though:

http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html

But your best option is to design things to account for the fact that the mobile users can't hover and instead watch for things like touchStart.

Comment: Oops. Just saw Boz's answer. That deserves to be marked as the answer.

Comment: thanks for the information and article. Very helpful. As you correctly said the browser will attempt to handle it and as a matter of fact it did handle it (opening the sub menus) fine. But since I change the <a href=""> to <a> iphone and ipad does not but androids do.

Comment: @user1400854 I don't know if that's a bug or not, but it's a known issue. Easiest solution is to give them null hrefs `href="javascript:'`. Alternatively, don't make them anchors.